# insert into database from duplicate textfield if not empty php sql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with 3 tables - Author, Study and Casestudy.

Author has columns `AuthorId` (Auto increment, `PK`), `F_name`, `L_name`, `Email`, `Contact`.

`Study` has columns `StudyID`(Auto increment, `PK`), `Title`, `Summary`

`Casestudy` - `AuthorId`(`FK`, reference `Author.AuthorId`), `StudyId` (`FK`, reference `Study.StudyId`), `Submitted`(datetime).

I have a statement which inserts data into each table (getting IDs of AuthorId and StudyID) and inserting into casestudy.

My question is if there is only one author how can I avoid passing data for the second author into the database. Otherwise it stores just empty row. An example of author webform https://jsfiddle.net/7un2yf9g/. It duplicates the whole container and creates an identical copy with different names.

My code is as follow:

```
$AuthorTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['AuthorTitle']));
$AuthorTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['AuthorTitle_ID2']));
$F_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['first_name']));
$F_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['first_name_ID2']));
$L_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['last_name']));
$L_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['last_name_ID2']));
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['email']));
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['email_ID2']));
$Contactauthor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['contact']));
$Contactauthor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['contact_ID2']));
$Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['Title']));
$Summary = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['Summary']));

mysqli_multi_query($con,"
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO author(AuthorTitle, F_Name, L_Name, Email, Contact)  
    VALUES('$AuthorTitle','$F_Name','$L_Name','$Email','$Contactauthor'), ('$AuthorTitle_ID2','$F_Name_ID2','$L_Name_ID2','$Email_ID2','$Contactauthor_ID2');
    SET @AuthorId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO study(Title, Summary) VALUES('$Title','$Summary');
    SET @StudyId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO casestudy(AuthorId, StudyId, Submitted) VALUES(@AuthorId, @StudyId, NOW());
COMMIT;
");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the way you have your variables defined at the moment Author_ID2 is never defined:

```
$AuthorTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['AuthorTitle']));
$AuthorTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['AuthorTitle_ID2']));
```

Here you just override `$AuthorTitle` with the value from `$_POST['AuthorTitle_ID2']`, and do not define `$AuthorTitle_ID2` at all.

Next, SQL statement as you have it would only link the second `author` with the `study` in `casestudy` because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` would return the ID of the last inserted record only even if there were actually several records inserted by one statement.

And finally, there is [IF statement in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html):

```
$AuthorTitle       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['AuthorTitle']));
$AuthorTitle_ID2   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['AuthorTitle_ID2']));
$F_Name            = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['first_name']));
$F_Name_ID2        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['first_name_ID2']));
$L_Name            = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['last_name']));
$L_Name_ID2        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['last_name_ID2']));
$Email             = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['email']));
$Email_ID2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['email_ID2']));
$Contactauthor     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['contact']));
$Contactauthor_ID2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['contact_ID2']));
$Title             = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['Title']));
$Summary           = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['Summary']));

mysqli_multi_query($con,"
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO study(Title, Summary)
    VALUES('$Title','$Summary');
    SET @StudyId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO author(AuthorTitle, F_Name, L_Name, Email, Contact)
    VALUES('$AuthorTitle','$F_Name','$L_Name','$Email','$Contactauthor');
    SET @AuthorId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO casestudy(AuthorId, StudyId, Submitted)
    VALUES(@AuthorId, @StudyId, NOW());

    IF ('$AuthorTitle_ID2' <> '' OR '$F_Name_ID2' <> '' OR '$L_Name_ID2' <> '' OR '$Email_ID2' <> '' OR '$Contactauthor_ID2' <> '') THEN
        INSERT INTO author(AuthorTitle, F_Name, L_Name, Email, Contact)
        VALUES('$AuthorTitle_ID2','$F_Name_ID2','$L_Name_ID2','$Email_ID2','$Contactauthor_ID2');
        SET @AuthorId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO casestudy(AuthorId, StudyId, Submitted)
        VALUES(@AuthorId, @StudyId, NOW());
    END IF;
COMMIT;
");
```

Comment: thank you for your help, however I have used php if/else. Statements are much longer but it works for what I need. Thank you again for your contribution

Comment: @Vlad Not at all. I agree the logic should not be in SQL text here. [Transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) can be as easily implemented through mysqli thus leaving all the logic right here in PHP code.